# HTTP headers missing with Kestrel on .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

Kestrel removes HTTP header values (e.g. Authorization attribute for JwtAuth) only on some clients. Local environment, no proxy. Direct connection to kestrel.

**1. Scenario: GET Request with Google Chrome (ModHeader extension): *As expected***

Received Headers (JwtMiddleware)

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEiLCJuYmYiOjE2MTU2MzIyMjEsImV4cCI6MTYxNjIzNzAyMSwiaWF0IjoxNjE1NjMyMjIxfQ.uqSLMn77q1hOFn67uZYgroget8JQL5dyzN42JMpB97g
Host: 192.168.1.12:5001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36
Origin: http://192.168.1.12:5001
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: wVYX6wN3FfJaQlgtFSjmYA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

**2. Scenario: From iOS App (WKWebView): *Headers lost in space***

Received Headers (JwtMiddleware)

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Host: 192.168.1.12:5001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Origin: http://192.168.1.12:5001
Sec-WebSocket-Key: PQZKp59eVM+V1Acj5s90ng==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
```

Authorization header was removed. No errors in the logs.

But the iOS Client is working fine:

[Result of WhatIsMyBrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99lwh.png)

**What I tried:**

- Set `options.Limits.Http2.HeaderTableSize = 1`
- Added support for request decompression
- Added global cors policy, allow any origin with any head and any method

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddCors();
    
                services.AddRazorPages();
    
                services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                    .AddHubOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
                        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                    });
    
                services.AddSignalR();
                services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
                services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true);
    
                services.AddSingleton<IUserServices, UserServices>();
                services.AddSingleton<ISessionServices, SessionServices>();
                services.AddSingleton<IPingServices, PingServices>();
    
                services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    
                services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
                {
                    options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
                });
    
                services.AddRequestDecompression(options =>
                {
                    options.Providers.Add<IdentityDecompressionProvider>();
                    options.Providers.Add<DeflateDecompressionProvider>();
                    options.Providers.Add<GzipDecompressionProvider>();
                    options.Providers.Add<BrotliDecompressionProvider>();
                });
            }
    
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IPingServices pingServices)
            {
                app.UseResponseCompression();
    
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
                    {
                        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
                        ForwardedForHeaderName = "CF-CONNECTING-IP"
                    });
    
                    //app.UseHsts();
                    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                }
    
                app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
                {
                    options.GetLevel = (httpContext, elapsed, ex) => LogEventLevel.Verbose;
    
                    options.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
                    {
                        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestHost", httpContext.Request.Host.Value);
                        diagnosticContext.Set("RequestScheme", httpContext.Request.Scheme);
                    };
                });
    
                app.UseRequestDecompression();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseRouting();
    
                // global cors policy
                app.UseCors(x => x
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                    .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials
    
                app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();
    
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                    endpoints.MapHub<SessionHub>("/hub/session");
                    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                });
    
                pingServices.Start();
            }
```

Comment: I don't see you include `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` in your `Startup.Configure` method, so it's strange. Unless your `JwtMiddleware` handles that. Not sure how you verify the received headers but I think there are possible chances for it to being working anyway (with or without `Authorization` header), it depends on how you implement your `JwtMiddleware`. For the missing of `Authorization` header, it depends on how you verify it. Yes, so please make it clear.

Comment: JwtMiddleware handles that. Authorization header is just an example. If I add an header named "test", it's also removed.